select language mode in vs code dont change
whatever i try to change the language from c++ to c in select language mode in the vscode, he turn back to c++ even when my extension is .c and my code is write in c, any help ?
i try change the settings.json,  but for some reason it didn't work

is this an untitled editor? a file? what's the file extension?

Please check your language mode in right-bottom of vs code

If the selected language is not c/c++, please click that and select your language(C).

Yes, that's what I am trying. It's showing c++ even when my code is c, and when I try to change it, come back to c++, when I try to use ctrl + f5 it doesn't work.
